# sql periodic function

Tags: oracle, math

There is an SQL function with date as argument

```
f(p_date) = mod(to_char(p_date,'mm')+1,2)*39 + to_char(p_date,'dd')
```

The values of f(p_date) repeat themselves with a peroid of 2 months, i.e.

```
f(Feb 7th) = 46 
f(Feb 8th) = 47
...
f(Apr 7th) = 46
...
f(Jun 7th) = 46
...
```

I don't catch a pattern here. Why is the multiplier equal to 39? Where do the 2 months come from?

What I need, is eventually same sort of function, but with a period of 40 days (or 1.5 months):

```
f(Feb 7th) = 46
..
f(Mar 19th) = 46
..
f(Apr 28th) = 46, etc
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the math is `((month + 1) % 2) * 39 + day`, so what it does is starting every odd month with 39+1=40, while every other month is counted normally from day 1 to last-of-month.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexeyKryuchkov, can you give more background about what you're trying to achieve and why?

1.5 months does not map to 40 days (or to any fixed number of days).

If you're trying to define a "40-day month", the easiest solution is to convert a date into an absolute day, then mod by 40.

I wrote a Q&A recently about the complexity of working with calendars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611348/9129668.

And adapting some of the code in that answer (which is based on SQL Server, not Oracle), the function you may be looking for would be something like:

```
((((DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),'0001-01-01',102), p_date) + 1) - 1) % 40) + 1) AS day_of_40_day_mth
```

But if you give me a bit more explanation, I might be able to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, from the beginning. I have a table named CS_LOG in Oracle, which is supposed to store the data only of last two months in "rotating" manner.
The table has a list partition over the field CS_PAR with 62 segments:
PARTITION BY LIST ("CS_PAR") 
PARTITION "P_CS_LOG_01"  VALUES (1)
PARTITION "P_CS_LOG_02"  VALUES (2)
...
PARTITION "P_CS_LOG_31"  VALUES (31)
PARTITION "P_CS_LOG_40"  VALUES (40)
...
PARTITION "P_CS_LOG_71"  VALUES (71)
Each partition P_CS_LOG_# of CS_LOG contains the data for a certain day.

Comment: Every 10 minutes new data is copied from another table and added to partition with the number 

mod(to_char(p_date,'mm')+1,2)*39)+to_char(p_date,'dd'), where p_date is a timestamp "current_day + hh:mm".

Once a day a job truncates the partition P_CS_LOG_# with oldest data, i.e. whose number # is calculated as mod(to_char(sysdate+1,'mm')+1,2)*39)+to_char(sysdate+1,'dd') 
What I want to achieve is to store data only of last 40 days instead of 2 months. I assume there should be 40 partitions and the formula needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: But as the rotating of data is organized in a "monthly" way, it seems that the number of partitions in the table should be a multiple of days in month.

Thanks and sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: this would be a lot easier if you first compute the age in days from now of each log entry and use that as the input for the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: @AlexeyKryuchkov, I think I understand what's happening, it's an implementation of a circular buffer, with the buffer partitioned by day - when a rollover occurs, the first partition will contain both new and old data, and the idea is to then delete the old data from that partition, leaving only the new data. What I'm not clear about is why it has "62 segments" but you've quoted values up to 71. As dlatikay says, you'd do better to calculate the whole thing in days. (1/2)

Comment: You need to convert the date into an "absolute day number", and then (if you want a 40 day cycle), `MOD` this by 40. You get an absolute day number by calculating the number of days between a fixed reference point and the given date. This will then give you a repeating pattern between 0-39, which can be offset by 1 if you want the range to be 1-40. Is that enough to outline a solution? (2/2)

Comment: I understand now. No need to stick to to_char() to manipulate the date. My periodic function can be mod(trunc((sysdate+i) - to_date('01.01.1970','DD.MM.YYYY')),40)+1 as you said. Yes, it is enough to outline a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the multiplier equal to 39?

The modulo expression will evaluate to 0 for odd months and 1 for even months. This multiplied by 39 is either 0 or 39. Added the day, the function will return the day for odd months, and 39+day for even months.

Thus,

**odd** (january)
1, 2, 3, ..., last-of-month

**even** (february)
40, 41, 42, ... 39+last-of-month

> Where do the 2 months come from?

The 2 is the argument of the [modulus function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm) (its divisor). The modulus function will return the sequence 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ... for the input 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... and so on. Mathematically the remainder. It is used to create the odd/even periodicity.

Comment: Hallo dlatikay. Yes, the multiplier 39 has to be greater than max days in month =31, just not to overlap. Does the odd/even imply that peridicity of say 3 or 1.5 month with such function is not possible?

Comment: the formula can be adjusted to any periodicity and offset. please add more information about your expected ouput to the question.

Comment: I need the output be repeated in a cycle every 40 days. The range of f(p_date) is therefore [1..40]. For example f(today)=1, f(today+1)=2, ..., f(today+40)=1, f(today+41)=2, ...

Comment: then what about gaps that are present in the original formula? would you expect f(03/01/2018) to be 29 when f(02/28/2018) was 28?